# SDK 2.0 rake file strips \\

Tags: rally

I had a script that was running locally, but it failed on Rally.

The reason it turns out is because the script contains the following line:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/Metrics/" + this.type + "/(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
```

This is so I can look for a particular string, based on this.type.  Unfortunately something in the rake file changes the \\d expressions to \d, which breaks the script.  This will probably break any script that relies on a double \ to escape stuff.

I was able to get around this by using [0-9] instead of \d, but it would be nice to get a more robust workaround to this nasty little gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed as of this [commit](https://github.com/RallyApps/AppTemplate/commit/8be48bcb7e458386aa130a829df2b8a096ec2c98). You can download the new rake file and rebuild your app.